# Ruby 3.0.6 for Mastodon 4.1.2: Ubuntu 22.0.4 cannot find version as the user mastodon

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv, ubuntu-22.04, mastodon

I'm a bit confused, and it's actually a Ruby- or more a Ubuntu-problem, not mastodon-related in a regular way.

For [Mastodon 4.1.2](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/releases/tag/v4.1.2) it's recommend (and necessary) to install Ruby 3.0.6. As root it's no problem. This version could be installed on my ubuntu 22.0.4 and `rbenv global` is set to 3.0.6. But after switching to the mastodon user, ruby 3.0.4 is still set (for `global` and `local`) and 3.0.6 is **not installed** and **cannot be installed** by `rbenv install 3.0.6` and it can also **not be found** with the `git` command!

`RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-jemalloc rbenv install 3.0.6`

results in

```
ruby-build: definition not found: 3.0.6
See all available versions with `rbenv install --list'.
If the version you need is missing, try upgrading ruby-build:
git -C /home/mastodon/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull
```

... and even if I try it with `git -C /home/mastodon/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull` the version 3.0.6 is not listed.

I can see `share/ruby-build/3.0.4` but the next is `share/ruby-build/3.1.0`. And both versions don't work to start the update process for mastodon 4.1.2.

I'm not much familiar with ruby, but it looks to me, that there is a different and a kind of standalone version of ruby, installed for mastodon as the user mastodon, which is independent from the installation with root, right? So, how to upgrade, if it's not possible to upgrade it like [here](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/releases/tag/v4.1.2) mentioned?

**Versions**

- Mastodon v4.1.1
- Ruby 3.0.4
- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- (no Docker)

**Update 2023/04/09**

Result of `rbenv install --list` ↓

```
2.7.6
3.0.4
3.1.2
jruby-9.3.9.0
mruby-3.1.0
picoruby-3.0.0
rbx-5.0
truffleruby-22.3.0
truffleruby+graalvm-22.3.0
```

**Update 2023/04/13**

Dirty solution (but without knowing the reason for the issue I described above): I deleted the folder and cloned it again.

```
rm -rf /home/mastodon/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git /home/mastodon/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Comment: in general, you upgrade the same way you installed it the first time  https://docs.joinmastodon.org/admin/install/#installing-ruby

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work as I mentioned above: `ruby-build: definition not found: 3.0.6`

Comment: "rbenv must be installed for a single Linux user". i guess you installed as root, and `rbenv` does not point to `/home/mastodon/.rbenv/bin/rbenv`, which you can try and call directly with an absolute path.

Comment: Both ways: It was first installed for the user 'mastodon' (during the installation you linked to) and after I installed it for other users as root. With root it's no problem: 3.0.6 is installed and global is set to 3.0.6, but as the user 'mastodon' the issues I posted happen. So, I need to find a way to update ruby only for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that helped... even though the real issue couldn't be found: I deleted the folder and cloned it again.

```
rm -rf /home/mastodon/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git /home/mastodon/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the command

```
git -C /home/mastodon/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull
```

worked for me. When I ran that command and then ran `rbenv install --list` version 3.0.6 was there right at the top.

```
3.0.6
3.1.4
3.2.2
jruby-9.4.2.0
mruby-3.2.0
picoruby-3.0.0
truffleruby-22.3.1
truffleruby+graalvm-22.3.1
```

And then I was able to install it by running `rbenv install 3.0.6`

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I described in the entry. This version is NOT listed (even after a refresh).

Comment: Well, it's a 1:1 (!) copy of what I already posted above in the entry. So it's redundant and it's also no suggestion to this issue.

Comment: Fine I'll delete it then. Good luck mate

Comment: Actually no it's not the same, because in your question you're saying it doesn't work, but for me it did work, so that's the difference. Leaving it up so other people can see that it might work for them instead of seeing your post assuming it won't work and still be frustrated. Anyway I hope you get yours working. Maybe try a fresh install of rbenv